# Making bash script continue after exec $SHELL

Tags: bash

I'm making a bash script that would install `rbenv` and `ruby`.

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install $rubyVersion
rbenv global $rubyVersion
```

But when the `exec $SHELL` is called the bash process is replaced by new bash process and the script stops (of course).

How can I make the script to continue?

Comment: ...don't invoke `exec $SHELL`? What are you trying to accomplish by calling `exec` at that point?

Comment: `exec` doesn't mean "run this and wait for it to finish"; it means "run this and don't come back".

Comment: After installing rebenv it is not loaded until I call `exec $SHELL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to achieve multiple objectives by modifying the `.bashrc` file then calling `exec $SHELL`.  Neither of those actions will modify the shell-in-which-this-script-is-running.  To modify the current shell, you want to "source" the `.bashrc` file.  Use the "dot notation" instead of calling `exec $SHELL`:

`. ~/.bashrc`

Good luck with this one!

Comment: Thanks! Well, I have tried `source ~/.bashrc`, but it is not working when I call it in the script. The script ends because `rbenv` is not found.
But when it ends and I call it manually, after that the `rbenv` is found and ruby can be installed.
Weird

Comment: `#!/bin/bash -i` helped! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

replace exec $SHELL lines with "$SHELL" lines or completely remove those lines

Comment: Not working. After installing rebenv it is not loaded until I call `exec $SHELL`

Comment: c.f. Eric's answer: `. ~/.bashrc`